# SQL Server version issue

Tags: sql-server

This [Snapshot](http://s4.postimg.org/m1rv0odm5/Capture.jpg) is the info of SQL Server Management Studio which am currently running.
as you can see its of version 10.50.1600.1
Now when i try to backup a file the below error i get.
So it states that i am having a lower version.
Can you please advice?
Do i have to update? If yes, then how?

[Error Snapshot](http://s27.postimg.org/jgjqw9nj7/Capture2.jpg)

can you guys please help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to restore a backup?

Comment: Could you tell us a little more? How are you trying to do the backup? Is this an in-house application? Are there two different server instances involved? I see the SqlClient and Smo namespaces...

Comment: Yes i am trying to restore a backup.

Comment: http://s1.postimg.org/8hs6soevj/Capture3.jpg this is the link

Comment: Yes i am trying to restore a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se we have t o explain to a programmer the difference between the management studio and the sql server? THe server does not care what version of management studio you run.

In case you do not know it, all you do when you do a backup is send a SQL command to the server. Management studio does nothing regaring the actual restore.

Check your SQL Server versions and upgrade them to at least 10.50.1600 - which would indicate a 2008 R2 version. You currently run 10.00.2531, which indicates 2008 Sp1.

Btw., all builds are here:

http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

And, btw., not applying service packs to a database is gross neglect. There are someimtes interesting issues (queries not working) and you seem to have a habit of never patching your system - both, your management studio as well as your server are service packs behind the current patching level.

Comment: Yes, i am new to sql server and all this :)

Comment: @user3235408 "all this" being computer and programming?

Comment: Thanks for the information i will try to install the new version.

Comment: Actually with SQL Server and Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try generating Script with `'Schema and Data'` option and executing that on your destination server.

Comment: Actually i only have the backup file... not the .mdf file